# Cannot find the symmetric key in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-permissions, symmetric-key

I have a permissions issue with regard to using a symmetric key under a specific user name when a stored procedure is executed.

Despite running

```
GRANT CONTROL ON CERTIFICATE::myCert TO myUser
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON SYMMETRIC KEY::myKey TO myUser
```

I still get the same error:

> Cannot find the symmetric key 'myKey',
>   because it does not exist or you do
>   not have permission.

The Master Key, Certificate and Symmetric Key were set under the database the user name relates to.

If I run the SP under Windows Authentication it works fine.

Here's the stored procedure:

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY myKey DECRYPTION
BY CERTIFICATE myCert

INSERT INTO sp_Password
(billEncryptPassword)
VALUES(ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('myKey'),@billEncryptPassword))

RETURN @@IDENTITY       
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY myKey
```

What have I missed?

Comment: Anybody got a suggestion on this???

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem even while running this as a SysAdmin.

To work around it I am currently closing all open keys which works fine. I'd much rather close only what I had open though.

CLOSE ALL SYMMETRIC KEYS;

--- Addendum

I just tried this with AES_256 vs DES encryption and the AES_256 worked on my end.

Comment: I have managed to get it working by adding sysadmin server role to the login but I'm not sure if this is a real fix as the login is supposed to be a website connection.

Comment: We've just had the same issue; GRANT did nothing, but adding the sysadmin role solves it. Did you ever discover anything more elegant?!

Comment: You really shouldn't promote to sysadmin. That would be a hack (and a dangerous one at that). I was able tog et this to work by using AES_256.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `CLOSE MASTER KEY` afterwards and that's messing with your subsequent encryptions/decryptions.